# PGF: How to customise legend style for stacked area?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

I produce the following chart:

[image]

I would like the legend entries to be symbolised by filled squares (like you would get with `ybar`). In the code below, I have already defined the style I'd like in `new ybar legend`. How can I apply it?

---

Code to produce the above:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}%<- use a smaller version if you have an older installation

\usepackage{color} % colors
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{cone}{RGB}{18,32,132} % blue
\definecolor{ctwo}{RGB}{255,153,0} % orange
\definecolor{ctwol}{RGB}{255, 192, 0} % lighter orange
\definecolor{cthree}{RGB}{0, 176, 80} % green 
\definecolor{cfour}{RGB}{255, 0, 0} % red
\definecolor{cfive}{RGB}{0, 176, 240} % light blue

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
date, monmkt, jeez, haha, srr, others
2Q18, 90.5, 18.3, 1.1, 50.08, 13.87
3Q18, 102.75, 15.5, 1.65, 49.91, 10.11
4Q18, 107.91, 19.2, 0.86, 48.81, 8.22
1Q19, 97.23, 17.3, 0.34, 51.42, 20.58
2Q19, 81.99, 9.2, 1.12, 52.2, 24.01
3Q19, 92.76, 10.2, 1.53, 51.75, 14.95
4Q19, 109.16, 9, 1.64, 45.11, 3.98
1Q20, 117.49, 10, 2.39, 17.96, 10.97
}\charttwentyfour

\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/new ybar legend/.style={
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
            \draw[##1,/tikz/.cd,yshift=-0.05cm, xshift = +0.38cm
            ]
            (0cm,0cm) rectangle (0.6em,0.6em);},},              
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\small
\begin{axis}[
x=15mm,
bar width=3mm,
axis lines=left,
axis x line shift=0,
enlarge x limits={0.02, upper},
stack plots = y,
%
% y ticks style and label
ylabel={index},
ylabel shift = 1pt,
ymin = 1,
ytick distance = 20,
%
% x axis ticks and style
xticklabel shift=0cm,
xtick=data,
xticklabels from table={\charttwentyfour}{date},  
table/x expr = \coordindex,                     
x tick label style = {rotate=0},
%
% legends and labels
legend cell align={left},
legend style = {fill = none, draw=none,
    legend columns=2,
    at={(0.5,1.15)},
    anchor=north,
    /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=2em},
},
]
%
% done with the axis, now the plots
\addplot [cone, fill=cone]
table [y=srr] from \charttwentyfour \closedcycle;
\addlegendentry{SRR};
\addplot [cfive, fill=cfive]
table [y=monmkt] from \charttwentyfour \closedcycle;
\addlegendentry{BRR};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

What an easy fix, after bashing my head for so long.

Adding `new ybar legend` to each `addplot` does the trick.

For instance: `\addplot [new ybar legend, cone, fill=cone]`.

Comment: You know, `pgfplots` already has such a style available (with rectangles instead of squares though), named `area legend`

Comment: I did know that! But I wanted squares rather than rectangles, haha ;)